# Nested for loop in R for combination of states

Tags: r, loops, nested

I have two dataframes in R, statedata with "state" being a column in it and topstatedata, with "topstate" being a column in it.
Total topstates are 5 and total states are 26.
I want to run a nested loop for getting the following combination in my data, so that each of topstate forms a combination with a state.
Something like this-

```
topstate   state
CA         AB
TX         AB
NJ         AB
FL         AB
NY         AB
CA         AE
TX         AE
NJ         AE
FL         AE
NY         AE
```

..... and so on 
Please suggest me an R code for such output.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function `expand.grid` in the following way.  I made up my own data.frames, so you will need to specify whatever df1 and df2 are in your script.

```
df1 <- data.frame(topstate=c("CA","TX","NJ","FL","NY"))
df2 <- data.frame(state=c("AB","AE"))
result <- expand.grid(topstate=unique(df1$topstate),state=unique(df2$state))
result

   topstate state
1        CA    AB
2        TX    AB
3        NJ    AB
4        FL    AB
5        NY    AB
6        CA    AE
7        TX    AE
8        NJ    AE
9        FL    AE
10       NY    AE
```

Comment: depending on your data, you may need to use the `unique` function as @sebastian-c did in another solution.

Comment: I'm glad for you.  I had a similar problem that I needed to use `expand.grid` on.  I'm also glad to know about the `unique` function.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop. This will do the trick:

```
setNames(data.frame(unique(topstatedata$topstate), 
                    rep(unique(statedata$state),
                        each = length(unique(topstatedata$topstate)))), 
         names(statedata)))
```